# How to create a campaign

Tags: civicampaign

I've been using CiviCRM for a few days now, and it's become pretty apparent that campaigns are a big part of how the system works. However, I'm unable to figure out how to create a campaign. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

After enabling the Campaign module and [adding your Campaign Type, Statuses, and Engagement Index](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/campaign/set-up/) (if relevant), you can add a new campaign from either the Campaign dashboard (using the Add Campaign button) or from the Campaign menu > New Campaign.  From the [docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/campaign/everyday-tasks/):

[image]

[image]